# what spring 4 configuration [java onfig] and maven dependencies for adding mysql and spring data in spring desktop application without hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

after searching for spring data with MYSQL ,all results are adding hibernate dependencies and it's config.

must hibernate be added to spring data or i can use spring data only without hibernate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring data required hibernate or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360789/spring-data-required-hibernate-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use spring without using hibernate. if you're looking for maven dependency for MySQL

Add following lines to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: may u share the spring config

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.
Follow the following tutorial --  
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-4-mvc-rest-example-json/

Add aforementioned dependency in your pom.xml
write MySQL code in customerDao class

Comment: I need simple spring data desktop application + mysql