# How call JPA methods with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have created a Spring Boot project using spring Initializr, choosing the Web and JPA dependencies.

I am able to make hibernate calls , e.g. save() - however the JPA methods (e.g. persist(), merge()) are not available.

```
//JpRepository.java

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface JpRepository extends JpaRepository<Jp, Long> {
}

//JpServiceImpl
import com.jp.jp.db.JpRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.*;

@Service
public class JpServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private JpRepository jpRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void readJp() {

        jpRepository.save(jp);   // is available
        jpRepository.merge(jp);  // this method is not available

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

[Spring Data JPA in an abstraction layer over JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360789/spring-data-required-hibernate-or-not/33363068#33363068), so you should use the `save()` method instead of `EntityManager`s `merge()` or `persist()`. Spring Data JPA does that for you. Look at the [source code of `SimpleJpaRepository save()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L506):

```
@Transactional
@Override
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return em.merge(entity);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because both [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true) and [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) interfaces don't have `merge` method.

You should look at [EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge-T-) for the `merge` method.